# how to install blackberry application from my webserver to blackberry mobile

Tags: blackberry, webserver

I developed blackberry application. i have the myapp.cod, myapp.jad, myapp.jar and myapp.alx file. I want to install my application from my server to blackberry mobile. What are files are need to the web server. i created the link like http://myserver.com/blackberry/myapp.cod. Buy i cant download and install using this link.  It shows the alert Download Failed. 907 invalid cod. HTTP Error 413: Request entity too large.

Please do reply for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check;

- Does your jad file list all of the cod files?  (I believe the tool is jadtool.exe or possible updatejad.exe and is included with the JDE -- it will update your JAD file with the individual COD  files instead of one large COD file).
- Are the individual COD files all in the same location as your JAD?